# jquery droppable and draggable not working on dynamically created tables in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make tables dynamically created in a for loop draggable and droppable. It is not working. For static table it works fine. Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aman888/tyLa53eg)

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button1").click(function () {
        for (var j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
            var table = document.createElement("table");
            var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
            for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                var tr = document.createElement("tr");
                var td1 = document.createElement("td");
                var td2 = document.createElement("td");

                var text1 = document.createTextNode("Text" + j + "-" + 1 + i);
                var text2 = document.createTextNode("Text" + j + "-" + 2 + i);

                td1.appendChild(text1);
                td2.appendChild(text2);
                tr.appendChild(td1);

                tr.appendChild(td2);

                tbody.appendChild(tr);
                table.appendChild(tbody);

                //var id = "a" + j + "." + i;
                //tr.attr({"id",id}).appendTo(table);
                // tr.setAttribute("id", id);
            }

            document.getElementById("tb").appendChild(table);
            table.setAttribute("id", "t" + j);
            tbody.setAttribute("id", "tb" + j);
            $("#" + "tb" + j).sortable({
                items: "> tr:not(:first)",
                appendTo: "parent",
                helper: "clone"
            }).disableSelection();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="button1">
    button1
</button>
<div id="tb">
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide further information on your problem. "Its not working" is not a valid problem description at all.

Comment: After I add $(#id) .sortable() codes, the tables are not even being created. It suppose to create 3 tables with 4 rows each. And the table rows suppose to be draggable and droppable. But they are not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add jQuery UI library to your project after jQuery:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

After that, your code works fine. Here is a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/kevenetewo/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thanks you very much, Arman. It works like a charm. I am relative new to programming. I put the code <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> in the <head>, it didn't work. but if I put it in the body, it worked. Can you please let me know why this is?

Comment: As long as you place **jquery-ui.js** after **jquery.js** and wrap your code in the `.ready()` method of jQuery, then it should not matter whether it is in the `body` or in the `head`. Take a look at [this example](http://jsbin.com/zahozedigo/1/edit?html,js,output). By the way, the recommended usage for `.ready()` with your version of jQuery (if your fiddle is accurate) is sth. like `$(function(){ your code here... });`. Check the [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/#entry-longdesc) out for the reasons

Comment: Thanks Arman, again. the interesting thing is that in your above example, where the library were put in head, sometimes, it does not work. If you click the button, it only gives the first table not all 3 table. But sometimes it works fine. Does it happen from your end too. By the way, thanks for the trick on .ready() infor.

Comment: I was using ie 11

Comment: I am sorry, @NZLearner I cannot replicate that on my computer. It works fine on all four browsers I have, and I unfortunately don't have an IE. :)